# Change regex unapply semantics?

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

Regex given:

```
val FollowRE = """(?i)(?<=follow)(\s+(me|@[A-Za-z\d_]+))+""".r
```

Code snippet:

```
"@foo follow me" match {
  case FollowRE() => "baz"
  case _ => "foo"
}
```

But it takes the `"foo"` branch. Can I allow partial regexp matching
so it takes the `"baz"` branch?

Answer (score 0):

The match has to have as many pattern variables (or wildcards, `_` to ignore the corresopnding capture) as the Regex has capturing groups. For your RE, that's two capturing groups, though I cannot make that match (I think the RE needs work).

**Addendum**

Apparently I missed the point. You want a floating match. Scala Regex matching in its extractor (what you get when you use it in a `match` construct) is a *match*, not a *find*. So if you want it to act like a find, you need to put `.*` at the beginning and end of your pattern.

Comment: I don't care about the capture groups for now.

Comment: Then you have to change them to non-capturing.